# Explicit equation of curve defined by $w=\frac{4}{(z+1)^2}, |z|=1$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

For context, I'm trying to find the geometry of the complex number $w=\frac{4}{(z+1)^2}$ where $|z|=1, z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Developing the expression of $w$ I get that $w=\frac{2(x-iy)}{x+1}$ with $z=x+iy$.

That leads me to the set $S=\{(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{-2y}{x+1}):x,y\in\mathbb{R},x^2+y^2=1\}$

Playing with geogebra I saw that curve is defined by $x=1-(\frac{y}{2})^2$, but I'm unable to get from the set $S$ to that equation. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: What is the question being asked?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon the question was how to get from $S$ to the equation $x=1-(\frac{y}{2})^2$, which has been already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your $w=\frac{2(x-iy)}{x+1}:$
$$\exists x,y\in\Bbb R,\;a=\frac{2x}{x+1},\;b=-\frac{2y}{x+1},\;x^2+y^2=1$$
is equivalent to
$$\exists x,y\in\Bbb R,\;x=\frac a{2-a},\;y=-\frac b{2-a},\;a^2+b^2=(2-a)^2$$
i.e.
$$a=1-\left(\frac b2\right)^2.$$

Another way to derive this cartesian equation is to write:
$$w=Z^2\text{ where }Z=\frac2{z+1}$$ for some $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $|z|=1$ i.e. $$|Z-2|=|Z|$$ i.e.
$Z=1+it\;(t\in\Bbb R),$ so
$$w=(1+it)^2=1-t^2+2it=\left(1-\left(\frac s2\right)^2\right)+is\;(s\in\Bbb R).$$

Comment: Actually $$w=\frac{2 (x-i y)}{1+x}$$ is also correct

Comment: My bad @Lozenges thank you